# C# Specification - Section 1.6.7.5 can someone please explain this example?

Tags: c#

I wanted to learn more about C# language and a lot of people have recommended digging into the C# specification, so I went and downloaded a copy of it from MSDN and started reading and going through the examples.

**C# Specification Introducton - Section 1.6.7.5 Operators**

> "The List class declares two operators, **operator ==** and **operator**
>   !=, and thus gives new meaning to expressions that apply those
>   operators to List instances. Specifically, the operators define
>   equality of two List instances as comparing each of the contained
>   objects using their Equals methods. The following example uses the ==
>   operator to compare two List instances."

I don't understand why the output would be ***True*** and ***False*** as opposed to both being **False**.

```
using System;
class Test
{
    static void Main() {
        List<int> a = new List<int>();
        a.Add(1);
        a.Add(2);
        List<int> b = new List<int>();
        b.Add(1);
        b.Add(2);
        Console.WriteLine(a == b);      // Outputs "True" 
        b.Add(3);
        Console.WriteLine(a == b);      // Outputs "False"
    }
}
```

I pop this into Visual Studio and sure enough I got both the Console.WriteLine() as '**False**' as opposed to both being 'True' and 'False' as specified in the comments.

It also states that the List-of-T declares a single event member called **Changed**, I could not for the life of me find it, I went into the decompiler and had a look as well.

Maybe I'm completely mis-reading it or I've got the wrong C# specification.

Comment: does the c# specification in question match the c# specification that you are using (differs by .net version)?

Comment: Not the first one to get this wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852596/listt-operator-in-the-c-sharp-language-specification-version-4

Comment: Please consider reading this for solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That passage does not refer to `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, but rather to a hypothetical `List<T>` class that appears in section 1.6.7:

> The following table shows a generic class called `List<T>`, which
>   implements a growable list of objects. The class contains several
>   examples of the most common kinds of function members.

*That* class `List` does overload operators `==` and `!=` to work as shown, has a `Changed` event etc.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I've been reading learning a lot about Generics and got caught into the "List<T>", I didn't realized it was referring to a previous section of the document. Good catch!

Comment: @NaturalFlaw: If you don't already know enough to say "that's impossible, something else is going on" it's easy to be confused. Really bad choice of name for this example.

Answer (score 5):

`List<T>` does not provide a `==` operator, so it defaults to that from `object` which is referential equality. You see the result `false` each time (and every time) because those two lists are not the same instances, and never will be.